# Divide table into 2 different tables in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a status column in my table and want to display pending and active rows in different tables in SSRS.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried yourself that is not working?
What documentation have you read that is unclear?
What example bit of code have you found that is close but not quite helping?
You'll get much better help from this community if you can demonstrate in your question you have done your homework before posting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same dataset for both tables where the results contain both pending and active. The way to make sure only Pending shows in one is to use the row visibility and check that status = "pending" and status = "active".

You can click on the row you want to filter and choose Row Visibility and choose the Show or Hide based on an expression.  In the expression you want to write the filter you want to hide. I have included a screenshot below.

[image]

You can also use the Tablix Properties by right clicking on the upper left hand corner and choosing the Properties and going to Visibility and using the same Expression.

The other option is to have two datasets where one checks for active and one checks for pending, but honestly it is easier with just one and you can filter it.

Comment: Thanks man, I am just learning SSRS and I realized it was a easy question i guess.